Typography component is not picking up the theme from the ThemeProvider
In this simple example I'm importing Material UI from esm.sh.
I create a theme which seems to be ok when I console.log it.
However the Typography component is not picking up the theme from the ThemeProvider.
Does anyone know why?
CodeSandBox
      import * as React from "https://esm.sh/react";
      import { createRoot } from "https://esm.sh/react-dom/client";

      import {
        createTheme,
        ThemeProvider,
      } from "https://esm.sh/@mui/material/styles";
      import Typography from "https://esm.sh/@mui/material/Typography";
      import CssBaseline from "https://esm.sh/@mui/material/CssBaseline";

      const myTheme = createTheme({
        typography: {
          h1: {
            fontSize: "1rem",
            color: "green",
          },
        },
      });

      const App = () => {
        return (
          <div>
            <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
              {console.log(myTheme)}
              <CssBaseline />
              <Typography variant="h1">heading 1</Typography>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </div>
        );
      };

      const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

      root.render(<App />);


If I append all of the import urls with '?dev' then the Typography component does pick up the theme correctly.   Here is what https://esm.sh/#docs has to say, With the ?dev option, esm.sh builds a module with process.env.NODE_ENV set to "development" or based on the condition development in the exports field. This is useful for libraries that have different behavior in development and production. For example, React will use a different warning message in development mode.

You have not specified versions for the packages as well, there could be chances of incompatibility. Try with one version and check the working, for example
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "https://esm.sh/@mui/material@5.8.0/styles"; import Typography from "https://esm.sh/@mui/material@5.8.0/Typography"; import CssBaseline from "https://esm.sh/@mui/material@5.8.0/CssBaseline";

@DarshnaRekha good thinking.   I tried each previous version until I found one that worked. 5.16.7 from 4 months ago works correctly.  The latest is 6.1.8.  Material-UI must have introduced an error.  Here is the working example with 5.16.7 https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nameless-moon-8xwxq4
